# History Viewers in Post

Tags: discussion, history

Is it still visible to everyone to see the history of my post here? I posted sensitive data owned by my company and they requested me to delete it. Unfortunately my post can't be deleted anymore because some answers to it so I just omit the sensitive data. Is it only me can see it?

Someone can answer me

Comment: This question is off-topic for SO and should be asked on SO meta, but yes, history of edits are visible. You could flag for a moderator to intervene

Comment: It looks like you already did the right thing by asking the mods to redact the post data. Granted, that was two weeks ago and it doesn't appear to have been done yet...

Comment: Even if deleted it would still be visible to users with more than 10,000 reputation points.